# How to rename an Excel table with VBA when I don´t know its name using "Send Keys" function?

Tags: excel, vba, rename, sendkeys

I´m trying to create a macro that can change the name of a table without having to indicate the table or the sheet names.

The only way to change the name of a table I found was:

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Name = "newnametable"

The way I found it best to solve this is by the "Send Keys" function, I tried to indicate with VBA to follow the commands ALT+J+T+A  and **rename the currently selected table** by the following code:

```
Sub NewTableName()

     Application.SendKeys ("%jta")
     Application.SendKeys ("TableNewName{Enter}")

End Sub
```

This works only when I put a button in front of the table and run it from there

The problem comes when I want to run the code from the VBA excel application. When I execute the macro this way, the send keys are played inside the VBA app, not inside the excel sheet I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid sendkeys as **all** cost. **Esspecially** when you're working inside a workbook. There are ways to reference every object or range or whatever inside a workbook.

I assume you're trying to reference the table by selecting a cell within the table then running your macro.

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameThisTable()
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Set Tbl = Selection.ListObject
    If Not Tbl Is Nothing Then
        Tbl.Name = "NewName"
    End If
End Sub
```

If I select a cell inside table2:

[image]

and run the macro, the table name changes from "Table2" to "NewName"

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: To get a reference to the Table the Selection is in, you can use `Set tbl = Selection.ListObject`

Comment: Really! that's fantastic. I'll edit my sub.

Comment: You'll get a runtime error if the selection isn't part of a ListObject.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, See final iteration?

Comment: I think you'd need to trap/ignore the runtime error, eg see https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables#activetable:~:text=Getting%20the%20ActiveTable

Comment: @CameronCritchlow yes, there are edge cases (the selection is not a range, the selection does not overlap a table, the selection overlaps >1 table, ...) .  With the info you've proved, I'd say it's up to the OP to build a complete solution to satisfy their use case.

Comment: @TimWilliams Great article, very thorough. I was able to get an error by selecting a shape or chart.